# Tests hang when running against firefox but the same tests complitly work with chrome

Tags: angularjs, selenium, firefox, protractor

- Node Version: `5.10.1`
- Protractor Version: `3.2.2`
- Browser: `firefox v. 45.0.2`
- Operating System `Windows 8.1 x64`
- Angular on web application '1.5.0'
- Selenium server 'selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0'

I'm new in protractor and my English is bad.
The situation:
I have a test (actually suite of tests) wich passes against chrome, but hangs almost immediately against firefox, it hangs after clicks on a link, after it should be done expects.

Test example:

```
var homePageAddress = 'http://localhost';

var someLink = element(by.css('.navigationpanel-element[translate="SomeText.SomeText"]'));
var someTitle = element(by.css('.titlepanel-title-first[translate="omeText.SomeText"]'));
var someOtherLink = element(by.css('[translate="SomeText.SomeText"]'));
var someSearchBox = element(by.css('input.search-box'));
var listOfItems = element(by.css('li.list-item'));

browser.get(homePageAddress);

someLink.click();
//It hangs here in firefox
expect(someTitle.isDisplayed()).toEqual(true, 'Some result text');
expect(someOtherLink.isDisplayed()).toEqual(true, 'Some result text');
expect(someSearchBox.isDisplayed()).toEqual(true, 'Some result text');
expect(listOfItems.isPresent()).toEqual(true, 'Some result text');
```

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine2',

    specs: ['chromeOrganizationCreation.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },  

   onPrepare: function() {  
        require('./waitReady.js');
   }
};
```

So as i said against chrome it works well but when it running against firefox it hangs after first click and even the browser window doesn't close.

Protractor log says:

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Increasing timeout doesn't give result, behavior the same.

A piece of selenium-server's log (end of it):

```
    09:49:56.693 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-11 << "{"name":"clickElement","sessionId":"c9f64f66-fc8c-4f3d-a0be-535b63370dd0","status":0,"value":"ok"}"
    09:49:56.693 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-11: Close connection
    09:49:56.693 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
    09:49:56.694 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 11][route: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total allocated: 0 of 2000]
    09:49:56.695 DEBUG [20] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver - Executed: [c9f64f66-fc8c-4f3d-a0be-535b63370dd0, clickElement {id={c0ac812d-747e-4bf9-9678-ae6025d656c1}}]
    09:49:56.695 INFO [14] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Done: [click: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (c9f64f66-fc8c-4f3d-a0be-535b63370dd0)] -> css selector: .navigationpanel-element[translate="SomeText.SomeText"]]]
    09:49:56.700 DEBUG [14] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Finished: POST /session/e92fa9f1-8822-4f27-85a2-9f929d484e4a/element/0/click
    09:49:56.710 DEBUG [14] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Handling: POST /session/e92fa9f1-8822-4f27-85a2-9f929d484e4a/execute_async
    09:49:56.712 INFO [14] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Executing: [execute async script: try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {
      var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);

      try {
        if (window.getAngularTestability) {
          window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
          return;
        }
        if (!window.angular) {
          throw new Error('window.angular is undefined.  This could be either ' +
              'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +
              'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\'s ' +
              'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');
        }
        if (angular.getTestability) {
          angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
        } else {
          if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
            throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
               ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
          }
          angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
              notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        callback(err.message);
      }
    }).apply(this, arguments); }
    catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [body.ng-scope]])
    09:49:56.713 DEBUG [20] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver - Executing: executeAsyncScript [c9f64f66-fc8c-4f3d-a0be-535b63370dd0, executeAsyncScript {script=try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {
      var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);

      try {
        if (window.getAngularTestability) {
          window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
          return;
        }
        if (!window.angular) {
          throw new Error('window.angular is undefined.  This could be either ' +
              'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +
              'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\'s ' +
              'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');
        }
        if (angular.getTestability) {
          angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
        } else {
          if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
            throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
               ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
          }
          angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
              notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        callback(err.message);
      }
    }).apply(this, arguments); }
    catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, args=[body.ng-scope]}]
    09:49:56.714 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
    09:49:56.715 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
    09:49:56.715 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total allocated: 0 of 2000]
    09:49:56.715 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 12][route: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total allocated: 1 of 2000]
    09:49:56.715 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055
    09:49:56.716 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /127.0.0.1:7055
    09:49:56.716 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 127.0.0.1:58730<->127.0.0.1:7055
    09:49:56.717 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-12: set socket timeout to 10800000
    09:49:56.717 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request POST /hub/session/c9f64f66-fc8c-4f3d-a0be-535b63370dd0/execute_async HTTP/1.1
    09:49:56.717 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    09:49:56.717 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
    09:49:56.717 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-12 >> POST /hub/session/c9f64f66-fc8c-4f3d-a0be-535b63370dd0/execute_async HTTP/1.1
    09:49:56.717 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-12 >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-12 >> Content-Length: 1172
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-12 >> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-12 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-12 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_77)
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-12 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "POST /hub/session/c9f64f66-fc8c-4f3d-a0be-535b63370dd0/execute_async HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.718 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "Content-Length: 1172[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.719 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.719 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.719 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_77)[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.719 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.719 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "[\r][\n]"
    09:49:56.719 DEBUG [20] org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-12 >> "{"script":"try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {\n  var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);\n\n  try {\n    if (window.getAngularTestability) {\n      window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);\n      return;\n    }\n    if (!window.angular) {\n      throw new Error('window.angular is undefined.  This could be either ' +\n          'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +\n          'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\\'s ' +\n          'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');\n    }\n    if (angular.getTestability) {\n      angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);\n    } else {\n      if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {\n        throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +\n           ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');\n      }\n      angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').\n          notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);\n    }\n  } catch (err) {\n    callback(err.message);\n  }\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }","args":["body.ng-scope"]}"
    09:50:25.970 DEBUG [13] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Handling: DELETE /session/e92fa9f1-8822-4f27-85a2-9f929d484e4a
    09:50:25.971 INFO [13] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Executing: [delete session: e92fa9f1-8822-4f27-85a2-9f929d484e4a])
```

Please help, I spend a lot of time trying to resolve it, may be I should open some issue? But I'm not shure about define certain steps to reproduce it without local application.

Updated

The problem described here:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4757

piece of log from my firefox driver:

`"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.SyntheticMouse] Calling fireMouseEvent mousemove 397, 205, ","timestamp":1461003932367,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.SyntheticMouse] Calling fireMouseEvent mousedown 397, 205, ","timestamp":1461003932388,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.SyntheticMouse] Calling fireMouseEvent mouseup 397, 205, ","timestamp":1461003932408,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.SyntheticMouse] Calling fireMouseEvent click 397, 205, ","timestamp":1461003932454,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.Utils] Not loading document anymore.","timestamp":1461003932478,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.nsCommandProcessor] Received command: executeAsyncScript","timestamp":1461003932504,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.nsCommandProcessor] Received command: findElements","timestamp":1461003934754,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003934917,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935029,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935156,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935279,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935395,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935518,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935640,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935757,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003935889,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003936015,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003936145,"type":""}
{"level":"INFO","message":"[fxdriver.DelayedCommand] Ignoring pending about:document-onload-blocker request","timestamp":1461003936273,"type":""}`

But i still don't know how to resolve it, what is `your comet request`:
`To solve the problem I rebuild selenium using following guide: http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-build-selenium-from-source.html
This generated my custom version of jar file.
Based on comment #28 I updated nsCommandProcessor.js and just added:
(request.name.indexOf('<your comet request>') > -1)
to
hasOnLoadBlocker = hasOnLoadBlocker ||
                         (request.name == 'about:document-onload-blocker');
so it would ignore the comet call.
nsCommandProcessor.js is under javascript\firefox-driver\js folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem described here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4757

There is two ways to resolve it: first described in below link, 
second is which we used: to turn on working signalR through websokets.
Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few reasons this could be happening.  My first suggestion would be to make sure webdriver is up to date.  Type this in your console:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Second, when you said increasing the timeout produces the same behavior, do you actually see a longer timeout?  If it's pausing for 5 seconds (default), then Jasmine think's its asynchronous.  http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-43

I would try (also as a good practice), separating your tests into `it` blocks.

```
it('gets the homepage', function() {
    var homePageAddress = 'http://localhost';
    browser.get(homePageAddress)
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('localhost');
});

it('clicks the link', function() {
    var someLink = element(by.css('.navigationpanel-element[translate="SomeText.SomeText"]'));
    someLink.click();
    expect(something).toBe(true);
});
```

This way might help Protractor handle the control-flow a little better.

Third, if those don't work, maybe try another way of locating the element.  I'm not too familiar with the `translate` attribute, but it also seems to be an 'experimental technology' and is not supported by any browser according to MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I update webdriver-manager before, also I tried to use last version of selenium-server-standalone it doesn't help. And I see a longer timeout if I increase it. Now I realised two things: 1. If "protractor" loads page and then do some expects, it works well even I use `translate` attribute, but I have only to add click on a link or on a button, It's immediately hang after clicking and does nothing after click.

Comment: This case works:

 `it('gets the homepage', function() {
  var homePageAddress = 'http://localhost';
  browser.get(homePageAddress)
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('localhost');
 };`

 This case doesn't works:

 `it('clicks the link', function() {
  var someLink = element(by.css('.navigationpanel-element[translate="SomeText.SomeText"]'));
  someLink.click();
  expect(something).toBe(true);
 }`

Comment: As I said it hangs after click, but there is no issues about click(); in firefox, I understand nothing. I tried to use other locators and result the same.

Comment: Now I also tried to write simple test on C# with two clicks and the result the same. I think it's something between our's web application(angularjs) and selenium webdriver.
And chrome somehow resolves this issue.

Comment: @Niyarlatotep yea I've had some minor issues with tests running on firefox compared to chrome.  Never specifically with `.click()`, but hopefully you can figure it out.  only other idea I would have is simulating the click event by via `browser.driver.actions().mouseDown(someLink).mouseUp().perform()`;  Other than that I'm not sure

Comment: Also, I notice your Protractor is the most recent release.  What about jasmine?  Try an npm update jasmine

Comment: Jasmine is the last version too. I think I found the problem see update in question above, but I still hadn't known how to fix it.